# How do you define a hasMany relationship for extended classes?

Tags: grails

Given the following (pseudo code) structure:

```
abstract AbstractClass  (in src/groovy)
```

And in grails-app/domain

```
class ExtendedClassA extends AbstractClass

class ExtendedClassB extends AbstractClass
```

How do I define that ParentClass (in grails-app/domain) hasMany "extended" classes?

```
class ParentClass
    static hasMany = [things:AbstractClass]
```

ie. any class that extends the AbstractClass can be included as a "child" of ParentClass

Thanks in advance

Comment: Grails supports `hasMany` for abstract classes, so it should work: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2583

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract `domain` class extending your `src/groovy/AbstractClass` and there define your `hasMany`